# Easy way to init a boolean List in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I realized that there is an easy way to init an integer array by using range(), or even just by saying e.g. [1..10].

Is there an easy way to init a `[Bool]` as well? (given that I know the size of the array beforehand). -- By easy I mean without defining a function just to do the init...

Comment: That's a list, not an array.

Comment: BTW, "initialize"/"init" is probably not the best word. Once a variable is defined as some value, it's not going to change its value in pure functional programming. Indeed, I'd use "define" instead.

Comment: I agree with chi. At first I thought you referred to what the operation `init` (the function) does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to initialise it with, if it is just a list of all of the same value then you could just use [`replicate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate)

```
replicate 5 True -- [True,True,True,True,True]
```

Answer (score 6):

As well as this solution proposed by Simon Gibbons, for a fixed size array where all elements are identical

```
replicate 5 True       -- [True,True,True,True,True]
```

you can also make use of list comprehensions to define more complex lists, for example to get an alternating `False`/`True` list you could do

```
[even x | x <- [1..6]] -- [False,True,False,True,False,True]
```